How should we handle outdated answers to questions?
As time goes on, some questions and answers are getting out of date. This is especially true of answers that cite behavior of specific, older versions of software in a general manner.
E.g.: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5391/1409

An unreleased version (well, it's released as a beta, but is intended to be a version release 0.8) of the bitcoin.org client alters the syncronization process, which should heavily reduce the time required to get the client functional. If I understand it correctly, the process will be faster through being less disk intensive.

That version is now released and the behavior is default.
How should we handle questions and answers such as these?

In the case of that specific question, where the question is still relevant but the answer just contains obsolete information, I think editing the answer is probably the best way.

Simply edit the post so that it reflects the current situation. 

Sometimes this, sometimes post a new answer. It depends.

I say we make a list - not only of answers that have changed, but answers that will change.
I'll start:

How much would it cost for a government to undermine Bitcoins?
How much would it cost to execute a 51% attack?
Needs to change when commerical mining ASICs begin being shipped.
What happens if Gavin and the other developers get hit by a truck?
What is the current (Feb 2012) "bus factor" of the standard client?
Needs to change when the list of core contributors changes.

Feel free to edit this.
